# How to Add values of column 2 at the end of column 1 if value of column 1 been duplicate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as shown below

```
[ID]  [  Company  ]   [ShippingCity]  [externalID]
 1      Microsoft       Bellevue         MM2547
 2      Microsoft       Bellevue         MM2548
 3      Microsoft       Seattle          MM2549
 4      Microsoft        Null            MM2550
```

I want to be able to have the name in one select statement and apply a logic that gives me name of company base on it.
I am using this logic :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SHIPPINGCITY IS NULL THEN CONCAT(COMPANY,'-',EXTERNALID)
ELSE CONCAT(COMPANY,'-',SHIPPINGCITY) ELSE **THIS PART IS WHERE i AM LOST**
IF SHIPPING CITY IS SAME ADD THE EXTERNAL ID INTO SECOND RECORD
```

I am aware that I can use only external ID but problem is client I am working with wants the first record without externalID at the end so they are looking for a result as shown below:

```
[ID]  [          Company           ]   [ShippingCity]  [externalID]
 1      Microsoft-Bellevue             Bellevue         MM2547
 2      Microsoft-Bellevue-MM2548      Bellevue         MM2548
 3      Microsoft-Seattle              Seattle          MM2549
 4      Microsoft-MM2550                 Null           MM2550
```

is there any logic that I can use to get it in one single SELECT statement?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:-

```
select
    id,
    case
        when ShippingCity is null then Company + '-' + ExternalID
        when row_number() over(partition by Company, ShippingCity order by ExternalID) = 1 then Company + '-' + ShippingCity
        else Company + '-' + ShippingCity + '-' + ExternalID
    end as [Company],
    ShippingCity,
    ExternalID
from [Your Table]
order by id
```

Comment: Thank you so much! simple and effective. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following logic, which makes use of the row_number to partition it based on company and shippingcity. Hope it makes sense to you.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, Company VARCHAR(255), ShippingCity VARCHAR(255), ExternalId VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,'Microsoft','Bellevue','MM2547'),
(2,'Microsoft','Bellevue','MM2548'),
(3,'Microsoft','Seattle','MM2549'),
(4,'Microsoft',Null,'MM2550')

SELECT  sub.ID, 
    CASE WHEN sub.ShippingCity IS NULL THEN sub.Company + '-' + sub.ExternalId
         WHEN sub.r = 1 THEN sub.Company + '-' + sub.ShippingCity
         WHEN sub.r > 1 THEN sub.Company + '-' + sub.ShippingCity + '-' + sub.ExternalId END AS Company
    , sub.ShippingCity, sub.ExternalId
FROM
    (   
    SELECT  Id, Company, ShippingCity, ExternalId, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company, ShippingCity ORDER BY Company, ShippingCity, ExternalId) AS r
    FROM    @t
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY ID
```

Result

```
ID  Company                     ShippingCity    ExternalId
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Microsoft-Bellevue          Bellevue        MM2547
2   Microsoft-Bellevue-MM2548   Bellevue        MM2548 
3   Microsoft-Seattle           Seattle         MM2549
4   Microsoft-MM2550            NULL            MM2550
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin , I did apply it and it works. the answer that Mat has works too.  @Mat Richardson  answer is based on row numbers and not in a sub query which makes it easy to read on code.
I really appreciate your help you saved me a lot of time.